# how to trigger function when receive FCM in background without tapping in cordova

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, text-to-speech, phonegap

im developing a cordova app with firebase cloud messaging. So the plugin i used is `cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging.`

The requirement is i need to have the voice notification (phone to read the text out loud when receiving notification). im doing this by using

```
cordova-plugin-texttospeech
```

However, I can only do this when the app is in foreground using onMessage function :
`cordova.plugins.firebase.messaging.onMessage(callback);` <= i put the TTS function in the callback

However, when the app is in background, this not works:
`cordova.plugins.firebase.messaging.onBackgroundMessage(callback);` <= put the TTS function not works, because the callback only triggered when user tapped the notification. I want it triggered as soon as they receive it

Anybody has any idea how to do this ?